# Azure: how to associate a reserved IP to an existing App Service (Not a VM)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to associate a reserved IP with an App Service and NOT a VM.

I have successfully created a reserved IP, but unable to associate it to an existing App Service.

Here is the list of commands I am using in windows power shell.

```
> Add-AzureAccount (successful) 
> Select-AzureSubscription (successful)
> New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName PrevigeoWebReservedIP –Location
"North Europe" -ServiceName XXX (unsuccessful)
> Get-azureservice -servicename XXX (unsuccessful)
```

My question is: Is it conceptually wrong to associate a reserved IP address to a App Service?  Is it possible only with a VM?

Is it possible to associate a reserved IP to an App Service, what am I missing here?

I am sure that the App Service with name XXX is present in the Azure subscription.  I have only one subscription as a matter of fact.

Windows power shell version is:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  187
```

`[Update]` Background: I am doing this to restrict only our Azure Wep App to access our Azure API App.  I am trying to achieve this using the *ipconfig* element in `web.config` file.  For this to work, I believe that we need have static *outbound* IP addresses, which are not shared by other tenants (else it will be a security issue).  In this context, I am not sure if a static inbound IP will help us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Web Apps work within a multi-tenant environment. So, in general, you cannot assign a reserved IP address to a Web App.

If you set up an IP-based SSL certificate, then a dedicated inbound IP address will be assigned to your web app. Not quite the same as a reserved IP (since it's not one you create/assign).

Comment: Just saw your edit - probably makes sense to post a diff question, but... you should look at web app vnets as well as App Service Environment (a premium tier service) which allows you to fully manage your app service network (as well as other stuff)